# How can I insert Data (Microsoft SQL) in the same table with same set of records but with different value

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a table Employee :

[image]

Need to Insert Same Data with different "Dept" in the same Employee Table.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name,  I have not uploaded or exposed any table or Data related to my work/project. I have uploaded an image of just a simple example for the readers of my question to get the clear idea of what solution I am looking for, which surely proved helpful cause I got the correct solution I was looking for, from Ihor. And when there is an option to upload an image to support your question, why cant we do so ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make insert from select, something like this:

```
declare @MAX_ID int = (select MAX(EID) from Employee)
insert into Employee (EID, Ename, Country, Salary, Dept)    
select @MAX_ID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Ename] ASC), Ename, Country, Salary, 'Recruitment'
from Employee
```

Comment: Ihor,  EID is Not an auto-increment Column. Now tell me how to proceed ??

Comment: Updated my answer. Did not execute this query but should be something similar

Comment: Getting the Error :                                                                                      Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Employee_2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EMPLOYEE'. The duplicate key value is (4).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Updated one more time:) It should be fine now